# How to call variable inside a string?

Tags: python, string, variables

I am trying to call a variable inside a string but cannot get it to work. I have tried researching this but cannot find a way to get it to work.

How can I call set_drive in the Drive part of soup = post. :

```
set_drive = "ON"

soup = post("""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Packet>
<Command>setRequest</Command>
<DatabaseManager>
<Mnet Group="18" Drive=set_drive Mode="COOL" SetTemp="19" AirDirection="HORIZONTAL" FanSpeed="HIGH" />
</DatabaseManager>
</Packet>
""")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call a variable"? Do you want to change the attribute name? Do you want to call a function?

Comment: In standard Python terminology, one does not "call a variable." One can only call a *function*. A variable can refer to a function in multiple ways. Which way do you mean--do you mean a *name* of the function is stored as a string as part of a larger string which is stored in your variable? Or do you mean something else? Where is the definition of the function? And so on. Please clarify.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommanded (and most readable and portable) solution is to use `str.format()`:

```
set_drive = "ON"

template = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Packet>
<Command>setRequest</Command>
<DatabaseManager>
<Mnet Group="18" Drive="{set_drive}" Mode="COOL" SetTemp="19" AirDirection="HORIZONTAL" FanSpeed="HIGH" />
</DatabaseManager>
</Packet>
"""

soup = post(template.format(set_drive=set_drive))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly!

However, if i wanted to call more than one in addition to Drive, such as MODE, how would I do that?

Comment: What about reading the doc and testing out things by yourself (python interactive shell makes such tests quite easy) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting. There's many choices in python.

```
set_drive = "ON" 
result = "Drive=%s" % set_drive  # traditional way
result = f"Drive={set_drive}" # python 3.6+ way
```

Comment: You forgot the `str.format()` version which is currently the recommended one

Comment: Not recommended by me. I recommend using f-strings and python 3.6+. The main (only?) advantage of `str.format()` is that it works across older python versions. So if you are writing a library, that's important. But if you are only targeting the current version of python, there's no reason to not recommend f-strings.

Comment: @HåkenLid: f-strings are literals, always. `str.format()` can be applied to any string object, regardless of where it came from (so you can define templates elsewhere). Use f-strings when targeting 3.6 and up and you have a literal, `str.format()` otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

set_drive = "ON"

```
query = 
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Packet>
<Command>setRequest</Command>
<DatabaseManager>
<Mnet Group="18" Drive={set_drive} Mode="COOL" SetTemp="19" AirDirection="HORIZONTAL" FanSpeed="HIGH" />
</DatabaseManager>
</Packet>
"""
query.format(set_drive=set_drive)
```

Comment: If you want to call more number of variable you can do simply. It takes argument in key value pair (dictionary).

query.format(set_drive=set_drive, Mode=Mode)

Comment: How is this any improvement over https://stackoverflow.com/a/51154374? Right now it looks like you just copied Bruno's solution as your own, with no explanation.

Comment: He was doing some post operation over his string format. In my answer, there is the simple string format. And down that, I also have explained what if you want to call more variable inside.